# How do I get PHP to display Apache's 500 error page when it encounters an error, instead of a blank page?

Tags: php, apache, fatal-error

I have apache directives set up for custom error docs for 404, 403, etc, as well as 500.  However, PHP, upon encountering a fatal error, displays a blank page instead of triggering the apache 500 response.

I don't need to display the error details or anything like that, as they are currently logged correctly in apache error_logs, so I don't think it has anything to do with error_reporting or display_errors, both of which are set correctly.

There are some similar questions here on SO, but haven't found an answer that does what I need.  Basically, in the case of something like a syntax error, I want to see the apache 500 error page, NOT a blank page.  This is not something that can be caught and handled in PHP, since syntax errors are uncatchable.

This appears to have been patched/fixed in php 5.2.4, as seen here: http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg28557.html

However, we are using PHP 5.2.17, and an upgrade is not feasible at this time.  Does anyone have any solutions / workarounds that might work to trigger 500 errors in apache for any PHP syntax/fatal error?

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 was released *after* PHP 5.2.4. Have you checked your php.ini?

Comment: Hmm no, tbh I have not.  Do you happen to know what option in php.ini controls this?

Comment: @RaúlFerràs I'm sorry no, I never found a solution for this.  We have moved to new servers though, so I believe our PHP is now 5.3.  I will have to check and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: @Kevin Jhangiani I've found that when an error happens in PHP, PHP is the responsible to manage it. So you will never be able to use the `ErrorDocument` directive as the error is "at PHP level". My blank pages were produced by php fatal errors, see this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/111065. I think this solution also serves for syntax errors in PHP >= 5.3

Comment: "in the case of something like a syntax error" - get a decent ide, this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works: register a [shutdown handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and display the appropriate page.
The shutdown handler should get called whenever a fatal error occurs. Make sure that you register the handler on top of your script.

Comment: That will work for many situations, and is the solution I was most often able to find, however it will not work for syntax errors (and other uncatchable errors) since the code does not get executed at all.  I'm looking for a way to make php behave similarly to perl, java, etc, and serve a proper apache 500 error, rather than a php triggered one.